# shapefile and multiple lines of census data QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to join multiple records to single feature?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/how-to-join-multiple-records-to-single-feature)

I am hoping to be able to link in the attribute table more than one line of data from a census entry per polygon.  for example 8 separate lines of names and demographic info.  I attached a spread sheet file to the attribute table but ended up with this in one continuous row or line; with "1" representing the id number for the polygon.

`1 Peltier  Jean 26 farmer 1 Gautier Louis 28 laborer`

in one line,

I want two or more lines like this;

```
1 Peltier Jean 26 farmer
1 Gautier Louis 28 laborer
```

Is this possible?  I want to keep demographic data tied to each person not within a continuous single line or row.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question has to do with GIS. If you edit your dbf in a spreadsheet software (libreOffice, Excel,...) then you can change the "on line problem". How did you create the data?

Comment: It is GIS because I want to collect census data and attach the data to a polygon (property) that is associated with the people in the census.  I would like to have more than one row, one for each person, linked by the polygon id number. ie each row with the same id number.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it as if you are trying to perform a one-to-many join. Unfortunately I don't think it is possible in QGIS at the moment, see: [Joining multiple records to single feature using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/how-to-join-multiple-records-to-single-feature)

Comment: You may of course use a python sript or plugin to extract a data set based on selected feature ID's. An example of this approach is discussed here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21881/whats-a-good-way-store-borehole-data-in-sqlite-spatialite 
But I guess that is not what you had in mind?